# How to redo merge conflict resolution after working with unrelated commits that came before it with rebase -ir?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

For a simple example, let's say we have a repo where an incorrect line was added to a file `a`.

```
$ git init 
Initialized empty Git repository in /someplace/.git/
$ echo "a1\nb2" > a
$ echo b1 > b    
$ git add .
$ git commit -m init  
[master (root-commit) 917f3b9] init
 2 files changed, 3 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 a
 create mode 100644 b
```

The branch `master` then forks off new branch `f`.

```
$ git branch f
```

In `master`, we then add another line to the incorrect file.

```
$ echo b3 >> a
$ git commit -am 'added b3 to a' 
[master e44bc9f] added b3 to a
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

In branch `f`, we do something unrelated, commit it,

```
$ git checkout f
$ echo c1 > c 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "added c"
  1 label onto
[f 7cb63b2] added c
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 c
```

then we move the line incorrectly placed in file a to file b.

```
$ echo b2 >> b
$ sed -i '/b2/d' a
$ git commit -am "moved b2 to where it really belongs"
[f 32cee76] moved b2 to where it really belongs
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Then we try to merge `master` to `f` but are met with the conflict that `master` added another incorrect line while `f` removed the first.

```
$ git merge master 
Auto-merging a
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ cat a
a1
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
b2
b3
>>>>>>> master
```

To resolve the conflict, we move the second incorrect line to the correct file, and commit the merge.

```
$ echo b3 >> b
$ sed -i '/HEAD/,$d' a
$ git commit -a --no-edit 
[f 28d8543] Merge branch 'master' into f
```

Then, we realize the commit about `c` should not be in this branch, so we "remove" it with `rebase -ir` and are met with the same conflict as earlier.

```
$ git rebase -ir $(git merge-base master @) # remove the commit about c
Auto-merging a
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a
Could not apply 28d8543... onto # Merge branch 'master' into f
$ cat a
a1
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
b2
b3
>>>>>>> refs/rewritten/onto
```

So, what's the simplest, most effective and versatile solution here to redo the previous resolution, taking into account what was added to `b` which does not appear in the conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a git utility for recording how a conflict is resolved so that you can replay it later.  It's called `git rerere`.

It's really meant for a specific use case - and as that use case is predicated on assumptions I disagree with, I almost never use `git rerere`.

I would also say that with a good workflow, the scenario you describe should be infrequent if not nonexistent, so I personally wouldn't start using `rerere` to record every conflict resolution just on the off chance that I'll need it again later.

But... as that's the question you've presented, `git rerere` is probably the "answer'.

Comment: The problem with `rerere` is that it doesn't seem to take the change I made to `b` into account. It only removed `b3` from `a` without adding it to `b`. I guess it only looks at the changes done on the sites that are marked with conflict instead of the whole repo.

Comment: @JoL: That's correct. `rerere` stands for REuse REcorded REsolution, i.e., the resolution for a previous *conflict*. If there was no conflict, there was no resolution, and nothing to record. Or, if the conflict happened before you turned this on, it wasn't recorded, so there was no conflict to have a resolution attached-to.

Comment: @torek I guess I have a different idea of what constitutes a conflict resolution. In this example, I wouldn't consider leaving `b3` in `a` to properly resolve the conflict, nor would removing it without adding it to `b`.

Comment: @JoL: Everything is on a conflict-by-conflict basis. Git takes the sections that would be marked-up (in the `<<<<<<< ||||||| >>>>>>>` region), strips them of line numbers and white space, and hashes them. Then when you finish the merge, Git finds the same same section of the same file and records that as "this is how to resolve this conflict". If a later `git merge` produces the same conflict (minus line numbers and white space), Git pulls out the same resolution. (Essentially, think of the cheesiest possible implementation, and that's what Git does :-) )

Comment: @torek I understand, it just seems wrong for git to think like that. It seems like a mistaken assumption that conflicts can always be resolved through only edits at the location where the conflicts are detected. There's not much I can do about that, though.

Comment: @torek Maybe this is what Mark meant by this being predicated on assumptions he disagreed with.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that comes to mind so far (that really isn't that great) is forgoing git and making a patch of the merge conflict resolution:

```
$ cp -a . ../$(basename $PWD)~
$ echo b3 >> b
$ sed -i '/HEAD/,$d' a
$ diff -ru ../$(basename $PWD)~ .
diff -ru ../t~/a ./a
--- ../t~/a 2019-03-08 12:54:34.701197573 -0800
+++ ./a 2019-03-08 12:54:56.761197321 -0800
@@ -1,6 +1 @@
 a1
-<<<<<<< HEAD
-=======
-b2
-b3
->>>>>>> refs/rewritten/onto
diff -ru ../t~/b ./b
--- ../t~/b 2019-03-08 12:54:34.701197573 -0800
+++ ./b 2019-03-08 12:54:54.044530686 -0800
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 b1
 b2
+b3
```

I can save that patch somewhere and apply it whenever I need to solve this again. The problem with this is managing these patches and having the discipline to either forsee when I'll need to redo the conflict resolution or always make a patch of every conflict resolution.

I would prefer a solution that uses git to manage this, though.

Answer (score 0):

`git rerere` or making a patch of `refs/rewritten/onto` is necessary because, with Git 2.23, `refs/rewritten/onto` will be removed in the particular case where a `git rebase -ir` is aborted.
"`git rebase --abort`" used to leave `refs/rewritten/` when concluding "[`git rebase -r`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r)", which has been corrected.

See [commit d559f50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d559f502c59658ea1f360fd28d8909894e40a4fe), [commit 37e9ee5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37e9ee5cb90db0831d5d58bed82149ba67917d73), [commit d3fce47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3fce47d2df868287de1a15d769e78db2c3283a9), [commit 7372eae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7372eaeb8b47ba96bad08777cd1330561ada8592) (14 May 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 88f95e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88f95e49afe2684da7e8074d7782eba396604bdb), 09 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase --abort/--quit`: cleanup `refs/rewritten`
>
> When `rebase -r` finishes it removes any refs under `refs/rewritten` that it has created.
>   However if the user aborts or quits the rebase refs are not removed. This can cause problems for future rebases.
>
> For example I recently wanted to merge a updated version of a topic branch into an
>   integration branch so ran `rebase -ir` and removed the picks and label
>   for the topic branch from the todo list so that
>
> ```
> merge -C <old-merge> topic
> ```
>
> would pick up the new version of topic.
>   Unfortunately `refs/rewritten/topic` already existed from a previous rebase that had
>   been aborted so the rebase just used the old topic, not the new one.
>
> The logic for the non-interactive quit case is changed to ensure `buf` is always freed.