# git rebase -r doesn't abort cleanly

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I did `git rebase 6ccf~1 -i -r` which shows a list of lines in vim and I changed `pick` to `r` for the commit that I would like to rename.

And next it started spouting stuff like:

```
...
Trying simple merge with 9f1...
Simple merge did not work, trying automatic merge.
ERROR: <redacted>.php: Not handling case 5ce... ->  -> 3e8....
fatal: merge program failed
Automated merge did not work.
Should not be doing an octopus.
Merge with strategy octopus failed.
Could not apply 13604c8... 9f12 9f12-2 9f12-3 9f12-4 9f12-5 9f12-6 9f12-7 9f12-8 9f12-9 9f12-10 9f12-11 9f12-12 9f1....
```

So I would like to undo what I did and I did `git rebase --abort`.

Now when I do git log, I see that my commit messages have been prefixed with `(refs/rewritten/9f1...`. How can I undo this cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

It should depend on the version of Git you are using.

This was [discussed in April 2019](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190507151530.GO14763@szeder.dev/T/#m5ccffd4fbc05d975f83e8980d5d0d573a5022c9c) and [fixed in Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57031323/6309) (Q2 2019)

> When `rebase -r` finishes it removes any refs under refs/rewritten that it has created.
>   However if the user aborts or quits the rebase refs are not removed. This can cause problems for future rebases.

Comment: On `2.22.0` here. what can be done on this version in order to exit cleanly ?

Comment: I suspect deleting refs/rewritten should be enough.